# Django api testing for get request with parameters

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework

I am testing.My code works for non parametric get request.But how to pass paremeters while testing in Rest api.

```
from rest_framework.test import RequestsClient
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
import django
django.setup()
from analyse.views_noquery import AverageTurnover

factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/average/turnover/start_date=2019-01-1/end_date=2019-01-1/')
view = AverageTurnover.as_view()(request)
#response = view(request)
print(view.data)
```

My views.py file

```
class AverageTurnover(APIView):
    '''Average Turn Over'''
    #permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request, start_date, end_date):
        dataset = requests.get(config['url']['API_FETCH_URL']).json()
        turnover_data = []
        for data in dataset:
            data_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['Date'], "%d-%b-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            if data_date > start_date and data_date < end_date and data['Open']>data['Close'] :
                turnover_data += [data['Turnover (Rs. Cr)']]
        return Response({"Average Turnover" : sum(turnover_data)/len(turnover_data)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary arg with `parameter: value` pairs, for example:

```
response = factory.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-endpoint', {"param1": "value1"})
```

That would generate a GET request with to the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-endpoint?param1=value1`

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get).